# Why DSolve giving Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation on this problem

Tags: differential-equations

Kamke's differential equation #574 has a solution, but Mathematica generates an error message as it tries to solve it. It still gives the solution.

My question is: What could have caused Mathematica to generate these errors? Trying this on Maple, it gives also the solution shown with no error message. Should Mathematica have generated these error messages?

```
Clear[f, x, y];
DSolve[f[x - 3/2*D[y[x], x]^2] + D[y[x], x]^3 - y[x] == 0, y[x], x]

(*{{y[x] -> 1/9 (2 Sqrt[6] x Sqrt[x - C[1]] - 2 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[x - C[1]] C[1] + 9    
  f[C[1]]), y[x] -> 1/9 (-2 Sqrt[6] x Sqrt[x - C[1]] + 2 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[x - C[1]] C[1] 
+ 9 f[C[1]])}}*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The Kamke solution is from the textbook: ("Differential Gleichungen" by Kamke, 3rd edition.)

[image]

**update:**

Here are 2 more ODE's that show the above messages, all with 10.3.1 on windows 7

```
Clear[a, b, y, x]
eq = y'[x] - a*Cos[y[x]] + b;
DSolve[eq == 0, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
eq = -Cos[b x + a y[x]] + y'[x]
DSolve[eq == 0, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I guess this problem is still not solved in V 10.3.1

Comment: Reproduced in v10 and v9 but not v8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the textbook solution, you can see/guess that `K$15888` is being substituted for `y'[x]` in order to reconcile the arguments of `f` and `f'`.  If this seems too wild a guess, you can confirm it with the following:

```
Clear[f, x, y];
kamke = f[x - 3/2*D[y[x], x]^2] + D[y[x], x]^3 - y[x];

Trace[
 DSolve[kamke == 0, y[x], x],
 _Solve,
 TraceInternal -> True
 ]
```

> Solve::incnst: Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation. After reduction, the bad equation is `2 (-((3 K$111077^2)/2)+x)-2 C[1] == 0`. >>
>
> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{
  Solve[f[x - 3/2 y'[x]^2] - y[x] + y'[x]^3 == 0, y'[x]]},
  {{{{Solve[f[x - 3/2 y'[x]^2] - y[x] + y'[x]^3 == 0, y'[x]]}}}},
  {{Solve[f[x - 3/2 y'[x]^2] - y[x] + y'[x]^3 == 0, y[x]]}},
  {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{
    Solve[{y[x] == K$111077^3 + f[-((3 K$111077^2)/2) + x], x == (3 K$111077^2)/2 + C[1]},
          {y[x], K$111077}]
   }}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
 }}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

The last `Solve`,

```
Solve[{y[x] == K$111077^3 + f[-((3 K$111077^2)/2) + x], x == (3 K$111077^2)/2 + C[1]},
      {y[x], K$111077}]
```

yields the same error messages and the solutions,

```
(*
  {{y[x] -> 1/9 (2 Sqrt[6] x Sqrt[x - C[1]] - 2 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[x - C[1]] C[1] + 9 f[C[1]]), 
     K$111077 -> Sqrt[2/3] Sqrt[x - C[1]]},
   {y[x] -> 1/9 (-2 Sqrt[6] x Sqrt[x - C[1]] + 2 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[x - C[1]] C[1] + 9 f[C[1]]),
     K$111077 -> -Sqrt[(2/3)] Sqrt[x - C[1]]}}
*)
```

The question is reduced to why this system should produce the messages. Strictly speaking, they seem more like warning messages than errors.  It gets tricky at this point.  Since it seems obvious to me how to proceed by hand, I have not been able to figure out or guess what the problem *Mathematica* runs into.

This produces the solution, with one `Reduce::nsmet` warning ("This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce."), but that just means that something else will be tried.

```
Block[{Solve = {ToRules[Quiet[Reduce[##], Reduce::nsmet]]} &}, DSolve[kamke == 0, y[x], x]]
(*
  {{y[x] -> 2/3 Sqrt[2/3] x Sqrt[x - C[1]] - 2/3 Sqrt[2/3] Sqrt[x - C[1]] C[1] + f[C[1]], 
    y[x] -> -(2/3) Sqrt[2/3] x Sqrt[x - C[1]] + 2/3 Sqrt[2/3] Sqrt[x - C[1]] C[1] + f[C[1]]}}
*)
```

So it does seem like a slight bug, slight in the sense that the warning does not prevent the solution from being produced.

If the following is a hint to someone, feel free to use it:

```
Block[{f = Erfc}, DSolve[kamke == 0, y[x], x]]
```

> Solve::incnst: Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation. After reduction, the bad equation is `-2 C[1]+2 InverseErfc[Erfc[-((3 K$132585^2)/2)+x]] == 0`. >>

```
(* the rest omitted *)
```

Comment: Nice analysis. As for the warning message, there is in effect a non-algebraic substitution for K$... inside the anonymous function `f`. The `Solve` code notices that a condition has been forced but does not then recognize that this condition is in fact implied by the input. Leaves a bit to be desired but it's the kind of thing that happens when we get outside of polynomial systems.